# Dead keys (accents etc) not working since LibreOffice 6.2 (since Ubuntu/Kubuntu 19.04 "disco")

Tags: libreoffice, qt5

After updating to LibreOffice 6.2 keyboard input of non English symbols is either ignored or leads to random behavior (for instance the cursor jumps to the end of the line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the issue is related to the [new qt5 integration package in LibreOffice 6.2](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/6.2#KDE_5_.2B_Qt5).

Uninstall the package [libreoffice-qt5](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/libreoffice-qt5). LibreOffice will fall back to less appealing default widgets (menus, buttons, etc.) but non English keyboard input will work again.

If like me you don't like the default widgets (they are too small) install the package [libreoffice-gtk3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/libreoffice-gtk3) and LibreOffice will use (nicer looking) GTK3 widgets. In Kubuntu a Breeze theme identical for GTK2, GTK3 and Qt is provided and you will notice almost no difference between the GTK and the Qt widgets.

Sources:

- https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=71437#c27
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1772678#p1772678

Comment: libreoffice-qt5 (1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3) does not cause the issue anymore in Kubuntu 20.04 (focal). But it does not seem to be fixed. Instead LibreOffice always falls back to a different widget, GTK3 if installed (which is my case).

Comment: libreoffice-qt5 broke again with Ubuntu/Kubuntu 21.10 "impish", removing it as explained in my answer solves the issue.